# Widget to display categories as tree in Django admin

Tags: django, admin

is there any existing code to display the list of some Category object in the admin of a Django site?
Ideally I'd like some tree representation like

cat_1

----cat_1_1

----cat_1_2

cat_2

cat_3

----cat_3_1

----cat_3_2

----cat_3_3

with up/down button to change the order.

```
class Category(models.Model):

    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name='children')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you haven't actually defined an order on this model - just a parent. You need something like [MPTT](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) which keeps track of the level and the position within that level.

Given that, it's fairly easy to write a `__unicode__` method for the model which displays the number of hyphens equal to the category's level:

```
def __unicode__(self):
   return '%s%s' % ('-' * self.level, self.name)
```

As for the up/down button, you'll need to write that in Javascript, I expect.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one widget, based on django-mptt :
http://anentropic.wordpress.com/2009/11/05/more-django-mptt-goodness-filteredselectmultiple-m2m-widget/

looks like what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

There is a [django-categories package](https://github.com/callowayproject/django-categories), which add a select box with all category to your admin site to manage categories.

Comment: I wonder if you could help with this question? What is the admin screen for Categories supposed to look like? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051740/django-categories-admin-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple

All you have to do in your view is get all objects:

```
categories = Category.objects.all()
```

Then in your template :

```
{% for category in categories %}
  <li>- {{category.name}} </li>
  {% for child in category.children.all %}
     <ul>* {{child.nom}} </ul>
  {% endfor %}
 </li>          
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating the desired tree like structure requires "Modified Preorder Tree Traversal" of the tabular data. A custom implementation will be fairly complex.

You can use existing package called [Django MPTT](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to simplify the hierarchical tree generation based on your Category model.

With it you can achieve following:

- get descendants of a node
- get ancestors of a node
- get all nodes at a given level
- get leaf nodes