# Django Categories: Admin not working as expected

Tags: django, django-admin, categories

I installed (pip) django-categories today, and added a field in my model:

```
categories = models.ManyToManyField('categories.Category', blank=True, null=True)
```

before running `syncdb`.

I have Categories in my admin, and I'm not seeing any file errors for treeTable or expand/collapse files, but I'm only seeing 1 level deep:

[image: http://www.circa1977.net/snap/admin-categories.png]

In the source for the page, I can see the child rows, but they don't show in the admin. Nor does a expand/collapse toggle.

The following doesn't seem to be true, either. I'm using fieldsets, and the categories field only shows up if I include it in the fieldsets in my ModelAdmin.

https://django-categories.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin_settings.html

I'm using Django 1.6.

Should I be seeing something else in the admin? How do I enable the treeview + checkboxes described in the docs?

Thanks!

Mark

**UPDATE:** This seems to be a JavaScript issue. I can see the treeTable.js function running on each TR. I can force it to initialize the table in expanded mode and see the child rows. But it never sets up the expand/collapse functionality. Still an issue, but now it's a JS issue.

I've been updating an issue on the github repository for django-categories: https://github.com/callowayproject/django-categories/issues/79

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was unrelated to anything within django-categories, though it's worth pointing out that Django 1.6 is bundling jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery.treeTable bundled with django-categories is from 2010. There's much newer code available.

The child rows and expand collapse functionality were getting loaded. They simply weren't visible in the Django Admin. I removed the negative margin from line 426 in `jquery.treeTable.js`. From there I modified `jquery.treeTable.css` as well to tighten up the UI a bit. I ended up further customizing `jquery.treeTable.js` to indent the category names in the change list rather than the checkboxes.

I copied both files to `project/categories/editor/static/editor` to override the defaults.